# Inserir checkbox dinamicamente pelo retorno de Json não exibe o Texto?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Estou criando uma lista de `Checkbox` de acordo com a seleção de um `Select` na mesma tela. No evento `change` do `select` é chamado via `ajax` `javascript`, o método que retorna um `Json` com *lista(valor, texto)* e percorrendo esta lista eu criaria dinamicamente meus `Checkbox`.

**Problema:** Os `Checkbox` aparecem porém ficam sem Texto na tela. apesar do `HTML` gerado estar certo ao meu ver.

Código:

Método que retorna Json:

```
SelectList lista = new SelectList(string.Empty, "SearchParameterId", "Name");
if (specificationId > 0)
{
   lista = new SelectList(db.SearchParameters
          .Include(s => s.Specification)
          .Where(sp => sp.Specification.SpecificationId == specificationId
             && sp.isActive == 1).AsEnumerable(), "SearchParameterId", "Name");
}
return Json(lista);
```

`Javascript` da `View`:

```
$("#SpecificationId").change(function () {
        $("#ParamsCheckboxes").empty();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/DropdownCascade/GetSearchParametersBySpecification', 
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { id: $("#SpecificationId").val() },
            success: function (categories) {
                $.each(categories, function (i, category) {             

                    alert(category.Text);
                    alert(i);

                    var br = document.createElement('br');                      

                    var input = document.createElement('input');
                    input.type = 'checkbox';
                    input.name = category.Text;
                    input.id = category.Value;
                    input.value = category.Text;
                    input.textContent = category.Text;

                    document.getElementById("ParamsCheckboxes").appendChild(input);
                    document.getElementById("ParamsCheckboxes").appendChild(br);

                });
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('Falha ao carregar as categorias N3.' + ex);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

por fim o dropdownlist e a seguir a div que eu tento criar os checkboxes dentro:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Specification, 
          htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.DropDownList("SpecificationId", 
             new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), 
               "Selecione a Sub-Categoria", 
               htmlAttributes: new { @id = "SpecificationId", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<!-- START CHECKBOXES-->
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        Detalhes Técnicos:      
        <div id="ParamsCheckboxes">

        </div>      
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END CHECKBOXES-->
```

Ele retorna pra tela os dados, eu coloquei um `alert` antes de `var checkBox = document.createElement('checkbox')` com o category.Text e ele mostra todos os valores, apenas não cria os `Checkbox`.

Exemplo do `HTML` gerado:

```
<div id="ParamsCheckboxes">
   <input type="checkbox" name="1tb" id="2" value="1tb" style="color: black;"></input>
   <br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="5tb" id="3" value="5tb"></input>
   <br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="20tb" id="4" value="20tb"></input>
  <br>
</div>
```

O `style` ficou por minha conta, mas é isso. **Alguma ideia**?

Comment: OBS: Ele retorna a lista preenchida pro javascript, mas nao cria os elementos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que está desenvolvendo não é a melhor solução, a melhor solução e fazer com que o **`Framework`** fique responsável na geração desse [html](/questions/tagged/html) (trecho de código), mas, primeiro criei um ***exemplo minimo*** de como seria a criação no formato da sua *ideia inicial*:

***Exemplo minimo:***

```js
function createDiv(id)
{
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  return div;
}
function createLabel(content, forId = '')
{
 var label = document.createElement('label');
  if (forId != '') label.setAttribute("for",forId);
  label.innerHTML = content;
  return label;
}
function createInput(type, name, id, value)
{
  var input = document.createElement('input');  
  input.type = type;
  input.name = name;
  input.id = id;
  input.value = value;    
  return input;
}

var divInput = document.getElementById("ParamsCheckboxes");

var d1 = createDiv('div1');
var l1 = createLabel('Valor 1', 'name1');
var i1 = createInput('checkbox', 'name1', 'name1', '1');
d1.appendChild(i1);
d1.appendChild(l1);


var d2 = createDiv('div1');
var l2 = createLabel('Valor 2', 'name2');
var i2 = createInput('checkbox', 'name2', 'name2', '2');
d2.appendChild(i2);
d2.appendChild(l2);


divInput.appendChild(d1);
divInput.appendChild(d2);
```

```html
<div id="ParamsCheckboxes">      
</div>
```

essa seria a forma como queria, pelo que pude perceber na sua pergunta, mas, existe como foi dito uma forma melhor de fazer algo sobre a seleção de um `select` e a geração de um parte de `HTML` (*parte, trecho*) atualizada.

---

***Exemplo:***

A idéia proposta seria a seleção por nível, e filtrando a criação de elementos [html](/questions/tagged/html) dinâmicos:

***Modelo (model):***

```
public class Item
{
    public Item(string name, int value, int nivel)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
        Nivel = nivel;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public int Nivel { get; set; }
}

public class Items : List<Item> 
{
    public Items()
    {
        Add(new Item("Seleção 1 - 1", 1, 1));
        Add(new Item("Seleção 2 - 1", 2, 1));
        Add(new Item("Seleção 3 - 2", 3, 2));
        Add(new Item("Seleção 4 - 2", 4, 2));
        Add(new Item("Seleção 5 - 2", 5, 2));
    }
}
```

são duas classes que faram parte do exemplo, uma é o modelo e a outra é a lista desse modelo para que possa ser feito filtro pela propriedade `Nivel` (o dados podem vir de uma consulta na sua base de dados, ou de um `ORM`, etc.).

No `Controller` em vez de retornar um [json](/questions/tagged/json) vou retornar um trecho de `html` (um [PartialViewResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.partialviewresult(v=vs.118).aspx)) com o nome de `_checkBox` como no código abaixo:

`Controller`:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private Items _items;
    public HomeController()
    {
        _items = new Items();
    }       

    [HttpGet()]
    public ActionResult Select()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost()]
    public PartialViewResult Select(int? id)
    {
        List<Item> model = _items
                          .Where(c => c.Nivel == id.Value)
                          .ToList();

        //retornando um PartialVew com modelo tipado
        return PartialView("_checkBox", model);
    }
}
```

A `View` `_checkBox` foi criada para facilitar na parte da montagem da sua tela, e seu [html](/questions/tagged/html) possui:

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.Item>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div>
        <label>
            @Html.CheckBox(item.Name, new { value = @item.Value }) @item.Name
        </label>
    </div>
}
```

esse responsável pela criação do resultado do filtro obtido na seleção do `input select`.

A `View` ***principal*** teria algumas modificações:

```
@{ Layout = null; }

<!DOCTYPE html>   
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Select</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        <select id="select1">
            <option>Escolha a seleção</option>
            <option value="1">Nive 1</option>
            <option value="2">Nive 2</option>
        </select>
        <div id="check1">

        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#select1").change(function (e) {
                var _id = $(this).val();
                $("#check1").html('');
                if (_id != '') {
                    $.post("@Url.Action("Select")", { id: _id }, function (data) {
                        $("#check1").html(data);
                    }, 'html');
                }                                     
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

O `select1` responsável pela filtro possui dois nível e quando for escolhido **nivel 1**, será chamado via [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) o trecho daquele [html](/questions/tagged/html) (`_checkBox`) em vez do `json`. Na `.change` do `select` foi utilizado [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) e configurado o seu retorno para [html](/questions/tagged/html). Pronto com essas alterações a lista é montada dinamicamente se problemas, facilitando as alterações, adição de [css](/questions/tagged/css), comportamento, etc.

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)
- [Classe PartialViewResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.partialviewresult(v=vs.118).aspx)
- [PartialViewResult in ASP.NET MVC controller](http://www.dotnetexpertguide.com/2012/09/return-partialview-from-asp-net-mvc-controller.html)
- [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)
- [HTML5 Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/html/)

Answer (score 2):

Segue um código que gerei que pode te ajudar, gerando Checkbox dinamicamente no MVC utilizando Jquery, espero que ajude.

```
$(function(){



        $('#Categoria').change(function(){


                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.RouteUrl(new{ action="GetSubCategoria", controller="Home"})',
                    data: {"Categoria": $('#Categoria').val()},
                        type: 'GET',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(resp) {
                        $.each(resp,function(key,value)
                        {
                           var newChk = "<input type='checkbox' name='SubCategoria' value='"+resp[key].SubCategoriaID+"' />" +resp[key].Nome + "<br />";
                           $("#ParamsCheckboxes").append(newChk);

                        });

                }, error:function(index, e, error){
                      alert(error);
    }});

        });

    });
```

Segue o exemplo completo no dotnet fiddle.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/cJmxBT